# Mount NTFS partition with german umlaute

Tags: mount, ntfs, fstab, locale

How can i mount a NTFS partition, which has german umlaute (ä, ö, ü) in the filenames.
I'm using the following mount command:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g UUID=5A9098309098149B /local/data -olocale=de_DE.UTF-8
```

Comment: Have you tried without the -olocale ? Which error did you get ? According to man mount.ntfs the use of -olocale is discouraged as it leads to files with untranslatable chars to not be  visible.

Comment: Umlauts work fine with my NTFS partitions without adding any special mount options (en_US.UTF-8 based Ubuntu).

Comment: i tried without the locale option, but when i do a 'ls' on the NTFS mount point i get strange chars instead of the german umlaute). Do i need some special package installed? Any special fonts?

Comment: How about adding "-o iocharset=utf8" (and removing the -olocale)? (Works for my OS X share (-t smbfs) and Norwegian filenames, don't know about NTFS.)

Comment: i tried this too, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the supposed options for mount, neither `nls` nor `iocharset` will help, as they are not even defined for NTFS. Consult the man page `man mount.ntfs`. Also, the default system locale is specified in `/etc/default/locale` on Ubuntu systems. You have not told us what locale you use, is it really `en_US`? That would be bad and so ’90s, as UTF-8 ought to be the standard by now.

Under a UTF-8 locale, a simple mount should do it:

```
mount -t ntfs UUID=5A9098309098149B /local/data
```

Other than that, I cannot help. It works for me.

Comment: I switched my installation from KDE to GNOME and now it seems to work fine. I assume in my KDE installation some packages or some settings are missing. I need to narrow this issue down further. But the initial problem is solved for now. In the end i did not need to specify the locale mount option at all.

Comment: This is incorrect, both `nls` and `iocharset` are defined for NTFS according to `man mount`. Strange though that they are not mentioned in `man mount.ntfs`. Perhaps a documentation bug?

Answer (score -1):

The locale locale=de_DE.UTF-8 in the mount option it's ok, you need then to change the system locale as well

```
/etc/profile.d/lang.sh 

export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
```

and restart the PC (or re-source the profile)

Comment: but i don't want the german locale used at all (the PC is set up to en_US). i only what the NTFS partition to be treated german, so i get readable filenames (with the german umlaute).

Comment: Either way i tried your suggestion, but it does not work. I also install the package language-support-de (to be on the safe side), but this didn't help.

Comment: -1 changing the system locale has no effect on the ntfs-3g mount options, also using locate= is discouraged (according to man mount.ntfs)

Comment: I noticed that setting the system locale does not work, but i haven't noticed any changes when i specify different locale options in the mount command. I wonder how is it suppose to work?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to add option `nls=utf8`.

```
mount -t ntfs-3g UUID=5A9098309098149B /local/data -o nls=utf8
```

Comment: i found this hint somewhere in the internet before and this didn't work too.